# how to create yellow line path for turtlebot linefollower using gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, python, rviz, turtlebot, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am totally new to ROS and Gazebo. Please help me with it. I want to create a **turtlebot line follower** using ROS , Gazebo, rviz, cv_bridge.
I am following the tutorial  given in
*(http://edu.gaitech.hk/turtlebot/line-follower.html)*

In this tutorial, they have asked to create a yellow line path. How to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357626/how-to-create-yellow-line-path-for-turtlebot-linefollower-using-gazebo?/) by [sree](https://answers.ros.org/users/56825/sree/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2020-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Lekha

The only thing they did is to generate a yellow plane with Gazebo Materials. You can check the Gazebo model that the tutorial is using [here](https://github.com/sudrag/line_follower_turtlebot/tree/master/Maps/yellow%20line). You should place the `yellow_line` folder than contains the Gazebo model on `.gazebo/models` folder to be able to use in the simulator.

Besides that, in this other [link](https://github.com/sudrag/line_follower_turtlebot/tree/master/Maps) you will find the specific Gazebo worlds the tutorial use so you do not really need to build the world by yourself.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sree](https://answers.ros.org/users/56825/sree/) on 2020-07-21**:
Yeah thanks, @Weasfas
but even though I created the model .it is not seen in the Gazebo simulator. Please me out.
I added the model in-*home/lekha/gazebo/model/yellowline*
I have created both model.sdf and model.config files

**Comment by [sree](https://answers.ros.org/users/56825/sree/) on 2020-07-21**:
To add the model in ***.gazebo***  it is not visible in the home

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2020-07-21**:
Yes, the folder must be in `home/username/.gazebo/models/`. You can also set up your custom models path: check [this](https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/177/gazebo-default-directory-and-can-not-insert-model/).

**Comment by [sree](https://answers.ros.org/users/56825/sree/) on 2020-07-21**:
Thank you Ia m gonna try .but when I am checking in terminal it is visible but when I wanna go directly and open that folder in-home/lekha it is not visible

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2020-07-21**:
Yes that is because by default folders starting with `.` in ubuntu are hidden, you can change that in your [settings](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-hide-and-unhide-files-with-ubuntu-desktop/#:%7E:text=To%20show%20all%20hidden%20files,to%20not%20show%20hidden%20files%E2%80%A6&text=To%20permanently%20unhide%20files%20and,and%20pick%20Show%20Hidden%20Files.).

**Comment by [sree](https://answers.ros.org/users/56825/sree/) on 2020-07-21**:
Yeah, Thank you . Its working